# Date format for iOS & Android

Tags: android, ios, json, date

We are creating an App for both iOS and Android, it will fetch data from a server, and one of the fields is a date range. We have decided to store a simple JSON as this:

`{
    "validFrom": "__date here__",
    "validTo": "__date here__"
}`

However I don't know which format fits best for this case. The main goal is to choose a format that can be easily used in both Objective-C and Java.

I've seen these formats in another question...

`"2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z"              JavaScript built-in JSON object
"2012-04-21T18:25:43-05:00"             ISO 8601`

...but I'm tempted to just store the number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970.

The main disadvantage of milliseconds, is that it is not human readable.

Comment: Either works. Did you try anything?

Comment: I'd use milliseconds since 1/1/1970, or seconds. Much easier than worrying about whether libraries parse strings correctly or not

Comment: The main disadvantage of milliseconds format, is that it is not human readable.
Just added a new line to the question. Is not a big deal for us, but just trying to find the right balance.